# How to use Hibernate HQL and AVG-Function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, average

I have the following Hibernate-Query, which works fine so far.

```
public static List<PerformanceLog> getStatistics() {
    return entityManager().createQuery(
            "SELECT NEW de.veliqi.selperf.model.PerformanceLog(o.useCase, o.description, o.totalTime) FROM PerformanceLog o",
             PerformanceLog.class).getResultList();
}
```

But I need to get the average of o.totalTime and I don't know how.
Using the following statement throws an exception, saying "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class".

```
"SELECT NEW de.veliqi.selperf.model.PerformanceLog(o.useCase, o.description, AVG(o.totalTime)) FROM PerformanceLog o GROUP BY o.useCase"
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx CSL,

but that wasn't the problem as grouping by one column works very well.

I figured out that the problem was, that the AVG()-function changes the type of o.totalTime into a Double value. That's why it couldn't locate an appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The basic query syntax is incorrect, you can't select 
o.useCase and o.description without either, using an aggregator on them, or including them **BOTH** in the group by clause

To fix, change the group by clause to:

```
GROUP BY o.useCase, o.description
```